# Get combinations of two elements in R

Tags: r

I need to find all combinations between two factors with two levels

Sex: Male-Female
Race: White-Nonwhite

I want my output to be:
Male-White
Female-White
Male-Nonwhite
Female-Nonwhite

Comment: Could you post the code that you have so far and indicate where exactly you have problems? I dont really know R but this simply looks like you have to use two nested for loops and print the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `outer` and `paste`

```
c(outer(levels(df1$Sex), levels(df1$Race), FUN = paste, sep="-"))
#[1] "Female-Nonwhite" "Male-Nonwhite"   "Female-White"    "Male-White"
```

---

Or with `expand.grid`

```
do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(lapply(df1[c("Sex", "Race")], levels)), sep="_"))
#[1] "Female_Nonwhite" "Male_Nonwhite"   "Female_White"    "Male_White"
```

---

Or using `rep` and `paste`

```
paste(rep(levels(df1$Sex), each = length(levels(df1$Race))), levels(df1$Race), sep="_")
#[1] "Female_Nonwhite" "Female_White"    "Male_Nonwhite"   "Male_White"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 10, replace = TRUE),
        Race = sample(c("White", "Nonwhite"), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Certainly no by me, but perhaps the OP wasn't clear and really wanted a different answer?

Answer (score 2):

When I read the request I thought it could be interpreted a couple of ways and that what you really wanted was a tabulation of those combinations. There are a couple of methods for this. Using @akruns example:

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(Sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 10, replace = TRUE),
    Race = sample(c("White", "Nonwhite"), 10, replace = TRUE))
with( df1, as.matrix(  # this results in a vertical arrangement
                 table( # this does the counting
                    interaction(Sex, Race, sep=" - ") 
                #`interaction()` creates a variable to be tabulated for each line
        ) ) )
#-------------------

                  [,1]
Female - Nonwhite    1
Male - Nonwhite      4
Female - White       3
Male - White         2
```

The ordering will depend on the levels. They are alphabetical by default but can be controlled.

I also considered using `xtabs` which is especially helpful if the tabulation totals are already in the data and you want to arrange them in a contingency matrix.